# Windows Search Service on File server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-server, indexing, windows

We currently have a Server 2008 R2 file server hosting DFS ABE Shares that are pushed out to our Citrix XenApp 6.5 (published desktop) users as mapped drives via GPO.  Recently there have been a lot of complaints that searching, since the move to this version of Citrix (and a subsequent upgrade from 2003 to 2008 R2 for the citrix boxes), yields results that are less than ideal.

After some searching we noticed that we had the old 2003 Indexing service enabled and that we should be running Windows Search Service.  Reading up on this I am really struggling to find the details about deploying it that I need.

From what I understand the server would require iFilters installed to allow it to index Office 2007 documents. With these it should be able to index all the files.  My question is though does the index on the server then get used by the Terminal Services clients?  Something I have read recently suggests that I would need to hold a local version of the index on each client by deploying Windows Search Service to each TS server and adding the network location.  Another suggestion was to add the folder as part of a Library but I can find no information about if this is possible via GPO and whether this is a per server or per user change.

The idea is to provide searching for users via Explorer that they are used to using rather than setting up Windows Search Server Express or a SharePoint site.  Any help greatly appreciated as I seem to be doing laps of the same KBs and TechNet blogs trying to find this information out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out how to do this in the end.  The setup was to have indexing configured on the file server and the directories were then indexed.  Standard Windows search on the Citrix servers would not utilise the index unless the UNC location (not DFS path, which is kin annoying) was added to a Library.  Once a Library had been created that pointed to the UNC searching made use of the index on the file server.

Hope this helps someone else out in the future if they get as confused as I did.